# Batch is scheduled but cannot see any run logs in 'Apex Jobs'

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a batch scheduled as can be seen in ‘Scheduled Jobs’ but somehow I am not able to see the logs in ‘Apex Jobs’ table.
Therefore , I am not able to understand if the batch runs or not.

I have also tried to query the DB and no results are coming besides the information that the class is scheduled.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you verified you have selected a view without filters on apex jobs?

Comment: post screen shots of what you see